# Difference between const and data memory

Tags: memory, msp430

I'm developing a MSP430 project, I'm using IAR Embedded Workbench to verify the memory usage. The print below ilustrate the information given by the compiler:

[image]

My doubt is: what is the difference between data memory and const memory? And what is +2 absolute in data memory?

Answer (score 0):

DATA memory contains initialized static variables, that is, global variables and static local variables. The data segment is read-write, since the values of variables can be altered at run time.

This is in contrast to the read-only CONST memory segment, which contains static constants rather than variables.

You can read more at [Data segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)

> +2 absolute

That means you have 2 bytes occupied by absolute located variables. They are located at an absolute address by means of special code constructions like

```
unsigned char port_register @ 0x1800;
```